# Using jQuery to switch background position every 250px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and not sure best way to change the background position, i basically need to change a background position every 0 -250px, then 0 -500px etc. What is the best way to do this?

JS:

```
function startAvatarAnimation() {

    var avatarHeight = 250;
    var avatarTotalHeight = 2750;
    var i = 0;
    var avatarSpeed = 1000;

    setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        if(i > avatarArray.length){
            i = 0;
        }
        $(".avatars").css({'background-position' : '0 -' + (i*avatarHeight) + 'px' });
    }, avatarSpeed);

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="avatars"></div>
```

I'm getting an error at the moment with avatarArray is not defined, this is my first attempt. I guess it needs to work out the height so it knows when to stop as well?

Comment: when or on what event ????

Comment: Sorry i need it in a function so when the function is called it will start

Comment: did you tried something yourself.

Comment: Yep, not have any joys :(

Comment: Show us what you tried so we can help you with your code. It will also give us a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly since it's not exactly clear.

Comment: no worries, 2 seconds will update question

Comment: Updated with code from what i have done.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by update the background every 250px.

Comment: I have a spite image which changes every 250px in height, so i need to calculate the total height of image and then on a timer go through and change the background position by -250px so then shows the next image in the sprite.

Comment: What isn't working about your current solution? What's it doing instead of what you just described?

Comment: I put issue in the question, its not changing and giving me an array error, the total image size i dont mind setting in a var so when it reaches that total height it stops and resets?

Comment: `avatarArray` is undefined in the code you've provided. Where do you declare and initialize `avatarArray`?

Comment: I dont, im new to this and this is what ive come up with. Im not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed with the following solution:

```
function startAvatarAnimation() {

    var avatarHeight = 250;
    var avatarTotalHeight = 2750;
    var i = 0;
    var avatarSpeed = 500;
    var avatarArray = {};

    setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        if(i > avatarArray.length){
            i = 0;
        }
        $(".avatars").css({'background-position' : '0 -' + (i*avatarHeight) + 'px' });
    }, avatarSpeed);

}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. `avatarArray` is an object here. You are basically comparing `if (i > undefined) ` which will always be `false`. That means `i` will never get reset back to `0`, and your interval will continue forever. You need to make `avatarArray` an array `[]` in the very least. Of course, it would be better if `avatarArray` had some purpose. It has no purpose here.